# Angular compile new dom with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in which there is a process I add new DOM elements.
For example:

```
$("#thingsAppendedHere").append('
        <div id="imNewlyAppended">
            <directive something="someObject" />
        </div>
');
```

which will produce:

```
<div id="thingsAppendedHere>
    <div id="imNewlyAppended">
        <directive something="someObject" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my directive:

```
someApp.directive('directive', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'directive.html',
            controller: DirectiveController,
            scope: {
                something: '='
            }
        }
```

and compilation is:

```
var scope = angular.element('#thingsAppendedHere').scope();
var element = angular.element('#imNewlyAppended');

$injector.invoke(function($compile) {
     $compile(element)(scope);
});
```

The problem is that after the manual compile the directive doesnt have $scope.something.
it seems it's scope is the #thingsAppendHere div.
I assume this is because i forced the scope while doing the compile.

What can I do to make it work? How can I tell the directive to creates its own isolated scope and to bind the '$scope.something' to outer scope '$scope.someObject'

Kind regards.

Comment: provide a demo that replicates problem. Also likely a way to do this without using jQuery to append to DOM.

Comment: ` scope: {something: '='}` create new scope. if you need, use $scope.$parent.something or remove scope: { .. } completely, and use $scope.$eval('something') to get value.

Comment: i have to add the DOM. i just gave a shortand version of my problem. regarding the second comment, the directive is in ng-repeat and it is bounded to the repeat element. I need to find a way to compile it correctly

Comment: Your approach should work fine. You don't need to care about creating isolated scope for the directive because it will take care of it by itself. It depends on where exactly you run compilation, look for errors. There's nothing wrong with these fragments of code, please, provide a plunker.

Comment: it is an app from my company which I cannot expose. I'll create something in plunker and will upload it. thanks for the comment

Comment: i found the problem. my new DOM element is actually a clone of the directive. I cloned it including the html content. once I cleared the innerHTML and compiled it worked. thanks guys!